# It is already 11:13 (UTC), but the SO snapshot did not arrive at the SEDE

Tags: support, data-explorer

It is already 11:13 (UTC) and the weekly SO snapshot is not yet on the SEDE. Last week it could have been synced until 05:09 (UTC)<sup>1</sup>.

Other sites look fine.

Are your scripts okay?

<sup>1</sup><sub>This is coming from a `SELECT MAX(CreationDate) FROM Posts;`.</sub>

Comment: Side info: the SO db is about twice so big than all the other summed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're impatient.

This is the [current status](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1239509/status-of-the-sede-refresh-on-sunday-0300-utc?cachebreaker=89867554):

[image: query result showing restoring StackOverflow_temp started at 2020-12-20 6:30:44]

The Stack Overflow database restore started at 6:30:44. It takes roughly 6 hours for this to finish. So it is either done in the next 6 to 8 hours, or it is stuck.

Allow for another hour or so and then I'll close vote this as no longer reproduceable.

Note that your conclusion that *it could have been synced until 05:09 (UTC)* based on the `Max(creation_date)` is not accurate. That date is the last post that made it into production *before* the backup was started. After that moment the first evidence of timing is from the creation_date of the database in SEDE. That is after the backup is finished and then it takes hours to populate the database.

During a restore the create_date of the database is correct but once the restore is complete the create_date gets updated due to a rename. See my question on Dba.se: [Which system catalog view has the create_date of a database which name was modified?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/267795/which-system-catalog-view-has-the-create-date-of-a-database-which-name-was-modif)